# Alter lines in a multiline TextBox programatically - Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How do we alter the text in a multiline textbox in Silverlight programmatically. I want to set or get each and everyline in the textbox. I have worked this in windows forms by the property in C#..

```
textbox1.lines = aStringArray;

textbox1.lines[1] = "Hello stackoverflow Folks!!"
```

But how do we do this in silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the text of a specific line, you can use the GetLineText ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getlinetext.aspx ) method :

```
var text = textBox.GetLineText(1);
```

Now, it looks like there is no existing method to set text of a specific line.